Why does `eval` not recognize a symbol as an argument of the function it is contained in?
I have this handy function:
(defun d-funcall-recursively (fun obj test1 test2 &optional formatfun collectfun atomfun restarg)
  "Apply FORMATFUN to OBJ. The result LST is expected to be a list. If LST is not a list,
  ATOMFUN is applied to it and the result is returned, or LST is returned if ATOMFUN is
  not given.

If LST is a list, execute TEST1 with LST and the index of ELT as arguments and, if TEST1
returns non-nil, execute FUN with ELT as its argument,

else execute TEST2 with LST and the index of ELT as its arguments and, if that test
returns non-nil, apply d-funcall-recursively to ELT with the other arguments set the same
as in the original call.

RESTARG is the argument provided by #'d-funcall-recursively to itself and to FUN. Note
that RESTARG can be a list, and, if so, arguments can be added during recursive calls of
#'d-funcall-recursively. [Not completely implemented, see description below.]

With this, any structure that can be made into a list can be recursed through, such as
folders. The results are collected using COLLECTFUN, which is #'list by default."
  (let ((lst (if formatfun (funcall formatfun obj) obj))
        (collectfun (if collectfun collectfun #'list))
        runlist)
    (if (proper-list-p lst)
        (cl-loop for idx from 0 to (1- (length lst))
                 for elt = (nth idx lst)

                 ;; We have to be careful to only pass RESTARG on if it is actually defined.
                 when (eval (append `(funcall test1 lst idx)
                                    (if restarg (list restarg))))
                 
                 do (prog2 (if d-debug (message "Picking up %s" elt))
                        (setq runlist (if runlist
                                          (funcall collectfun runlist (funcall fun elt))
                                        (funcall fun elt))))
                 else when (funcall test2 lst idx)
                 do (prog2 (if d-debug (message "Recursing into %s" elt))
                        (setq runlist (if runlist (funcall collectfun
                                                           runlist
                                                           (d-funcall-recursively fun elt test1 test2 formatfun collectfun atomfun))
                                        (d-funcall-recursively fun elt test1 test2 formatfun collectfun atomfun))))
                 finally return runlist)
      (if atomfun (funcall atomfun lst) lst))))

which has often been useful to define more elementary functions. But now I would need it to pick up and pass on arguments as it recurses. For this, I've introduced RESTARG, which is supposed to be passed on and potentially modified as the function progresses and finally be passed on to FUN. This is not implemented yet, but in theory it seems clear what to do. The problem is though that I've used this function a few times before I introduced RESTARG, so that functions using it wouldn't have the right number of arguments. For instance, I have this function:
(defun d-recurse-through-directory (fun dir test &optional collectfun allfiles dirtest)
  "Recurse through DIR, applying FUN to each file that satisfies TEST. If COLLECTFUN is
given, results are collected using it (see the documentation of d-funcall-recursively),
otherwise they are collected using #'list, preserving the directory structure as a list;
otherwise, they are collected in a list.

If ALLFILES is t, hidden files are included.

 If DIRTEST is given, it should be a function that takes as input the name of a directory
and returns t if the directory should be recursed into (otherwise all directories are
recursed into)."
  (d-funcall-recursively
   fun dir
   (lambda (lst idx)
     (let ((file (nth idx lst)))
       (and (not (file-directory-p file))
            (funcall test file))))
   (lambda (lst idx)
     (and (file-directory-p (nth idx lst))
          (if dirtest (funcall dirtest (nth idx lst)) t)))
   (lambda (d)
     (directory-files d t (unless allfiles "\\`[^.]")))
   collectfun))

which uses two test functions having two arguments each, one to test for directories that should be recursed into and one for files that should be acted on. If I now add RESTARG as an argument to FUN, TEST1 and TEST2 in d-funcall-recursively, then Emacs throws a wrong number of arguments error even if RESTARG is not given (and thus assumed nil). Moreover, RESTARG is supposed to be an optional argument anyway. So I thought I could cleverly avoid the issue by using a macro that would create an expression that contained RESTARG only if it was non-nil, and only then evaluating that expression. This is what I tried out with TEST1 in the middle section of d-funcall-recursively:
when (eval (append `(funcall test1 lst idx)
                   (if restarg (list restarg))))

Here, the backquote should quote an expression to which RESTARG is then appended if and only if it exists. And that part works: when I do
(let ((restarg 'b)) (append `(funcall test1 lst idx)
                            (if restarg (list restarg))))

I get
(funcall test1 lst idx b)

, but when the eval evaluates, say, when I do
(d-recurse-through-directory (lambda (filepath) filepath)
                             d-emacs-directory
                             (lambda (filepath) t))

Then I get an error
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable test1)
(funcall test1 lst idx)
eval((funcall test1 lst idx))
(if (eval (append '(funcall test1 lst idx) (if restarg (list restarg)))) (progn (progn (if d-debug (message "Picking up %s" elt)) (prog1 (setq runlist (if runlist (funcall collectfun runlist (funcall fun elt)) (funcall fun elt)))))) (if (funcall test2 lst idx) (progn (progn (if d-debug (message "Recursing into %s" elt)) (prog1 (setq runlist (if runlist (funcall collectfun runlist ...) (d-funcall-recursively fun elt test1 test2 formatfun collectfun atomfun))))))))

So I tried putting a comma before test1 so its value is inserted when the backquote is evaluated:
when (eval (append `(funcall ,test1 lst idx)
                   (if restarg (list restarg))))

but then the error goes to the next argument:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable lst)
(funcall #f(lambda (lst idx) [(test #f(lambda (filepath) [t] t))] (let ((file (nth idx lst))) (and (not (file-directory-p file)) (funcall test file)))) lst idx)

and when I put a comma in front of all three arguments of funcall, then I get an error because they have been evaluated:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-function "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/#d-emacs-eshell.el#")
("/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/#d-emacs-eshell.el#" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/#d-emacs-ynta.el#" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/#prompt#" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/#prompt.el#" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/d-emacs-pkg.el" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/d-emacs.el" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/pkg-configs" "/home/alex/.emacs.d/site-lisp/Daselt/d-emacs/snippets")
(funcall #f(lambda (lst idx) [(test #f(lambda (filepath) [t] t))] (let ((file (nth idx lst))) (and (not (file-directory-p file)) (funcall test file))))

So I don't get it: why does the eval not understand that TEST1 is an argument of the function it is contained in, and how can I do this macro correctly?

Your question has a bunch of extraneous detail that obscures what you’re really asking, but it all boils down to figuring out why this code doesn’t work:
(let ((q 42))
  (eval 'q))

The answer is in the documentation:
Evaluate FORM and return its value.

If LEXICAL is t, evaluate using lexical scoping.
LEXICAL can also be an actual lexical environment, in the form of an
alist mapping symbols to their value.

By default eval evaluates the code in the global environment, not the lexical one. Our variable q doesn’t exist in the global environment, so it naturally generates an error.
But more importantly, you’re doing something really odd. You never, ever need to call eval on a list that you produced yourself. (eval (list …)) is always wrong, no matter what you are doing. Instead of quoting something and then evaluating it, just don’t quote it. In your case you are doing (eval '(funcall test1 lst idx)), which is always just equivalent to running that code directly as (funcall test1 lst idx).

Oh, I should have seen that. But what you're writing in the last paragraph misses the point: I want test1 to have restargs as argument if and only if it is non-nil (or is given). Just removing it doesn't work for that.

No, I simply didn’t address that at all. There are other obvious solutions that that which have nothing to do with your question about eval.

Well, I included the context because I thought there might be other solutions that I might not see. What solutions are you thinking of?

You really need to stick to one question per Question, but to make a long story short you need to just change the signature of the callback function to include the optional argument.

But the purpose of the macro is that functions are accepted that only take two inputs when restargs isn't necessary. More importantly though, if I evaluate (let ((q 42))   (eval 'q t)) I still get a void-variable error. Why is that when it should have activated lexical scoping? Sorry, I think I actually tried this before asking the Question, but thought I had screwed something up when I read your answer and only today got to continue working on that part of the program. I can set up a lexical environment that specifies q and it works, but I don't understand why supplying t doesn't.
